# Check for individual words in a string

Tags: python, user-input

I am creating a program and what I want it to do is check the users input and compare it to a dictionary to see if that word is in the dictionary.

original code:

```
dic = "goodmorning" + "wakeup"
test = raw_input("test: ")
if test == dic:
    print "hello"
else:
    print "testf"
```

I have tried this but if I were to enter `morning` or `morningwake` it will print hello.
I have also tried this:

```
dic = ["goodmorning", "wakeup"]
test = raw_input("test: ")
if test == dic:
    print "hello"
else:
    print "testf"
```

This will also not work either.

Comment: `dic = ["goodmorning", "wakeup"]` is not a dictionary, it is a list. And also `dic = "goodmorning" + "wakeup"` is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in`, not `==`.

```
dic = ["goodmorning", "wakeup"]
test = raw_input("test: ")
if test in dic:
    print "hello"
else:
    print "testf"
```